# three.js undefined has no properties PlaneGeometry vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I'm having an issue with THREEJS, I'm using PlaneGeometry and two functions to create a 3D wave effect I keep getting a JS error about vertices.

The error reads :

> undefined has no properties

Here's the first function :

```
function updatePLane() {
            for (var i = 0; i < planeGeo.vertices.length; i++) {
                planeGeo.vertices[i].z += Math.random() * vertexHeight - vertexHeight;
                planeGeo.vertices[i]._myZ = planeGeo.vertices[i].z
            }
        }
```

And the second one :

```
function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            camera.position.z -= 150;
            var x = camera.position.x;
            var camZ = camera.position.z;
            camera.position.z = camZ * Math.cos(0.001) - x * Math.sin(0.001) - 10;
            camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 8000, 0))

            for (var c = 0; 1 < planeGeo.vertices.length;c++) {
        
                planeGeo.vertices[c].z = Math.sin((1 + count * 0.00002)) * (planeGeo.vertices[c]._myZ - (planeGeo.vertices[c]._myZ * 0.6));
                plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

                count += 0.1;
            }
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
```

The issue I'm having is that the JS error only occurs for the second function which uses the same syntax as the first one only replacing

> planeGeo.vertices[i]

to

> planeGeo.vertices[c]

Edit :
As prisoner849 said I just had to replace

```
for (var c = 0; 1 < planeGeo.vertices.length;c++)
```

With

```
for (var c = 0; c < planeGeo.vertices.length;c++)
```

Comment: "1 <" ? Shouldn't it be "c <" ?

Comment: You're absolutely right I can't believe I spent hours without seeing it, it works perfectly now, thank you

Comment: You're welcome :)